# How to properly delete a record from a database in one query? JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How to properly delete a record from a database in one query. For example, when an entity uses the primary key of the parent entity using the @MapsId annotation, if the parent entry is deleted, it will swear that the parent's id is used in the child entity.

Code example :

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;
    private String name;
}


@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String phone;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private User user;
}
```

Here, when deleting a User using the JpaRepository delete method, an error will occur that the UserDetail uses the primary key User

Comment: check the usage of cascade = CascadeType.DELETE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you sure the direction of the relation makes sense? I would have expected it to be the other way around, because the user ID and name seem to be the more basic info that you need more often.

Second, what you're doing seems like an attempt to optimize performance, because you could just as well store all the data in a single entity. Are you sure the optimization pays off? (I would guess not.) See [Premature Optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Third, *if* the relation was the other way around, you could modify the annotation to `@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DELETE)` or `@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` to let JPA automatically delete the other entity when the first is deleted.

Comment: yes i want to get rid of the extra columns in the table and use the parent's key in the child entities.
I can't delete an entry in the User entity with one request until I delete it in UserDetails , even if I specify a cascade. Error update or delete on table "usr" violates foreign key constraint "fkna1ypplp" on table "user_details"

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to delete all foreign keys with used by primary key

or by using **cascade**

After that use below

In JPA we can use **deleteById**

or **by named query**

DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID = ?1

or **my native query**

delete from employee where id = ?1